# Google\Spreadsheet запись со 2 строки

Tags: google-spreadsheet, phpspreadsheet

Я записываю 8 массивов на 1 лист в разные колонки.
1 массив записался нормально, а второй и далее начинает записывать со строки следующей после той где закончил писать предыдущий массив. И получается что данные записываются нисходящей лесенкой.

Как мне указать в $listFeed->insert() что писать нужно всегда со 2 строки?

Comment: Приложите пример кода

Comment: foreach ($arr as $item ){
                $listFeed->insert([
                    "number".$numberColumn =>  $item['number'],
                    "nic".$numberColumn =>  $item['nic'],
                    "country".$numberColumn =>  $item['country'],
                    "ball".$numberColumn =>  $item['ball'],
                    "prize".$numberColumn =>  $item['prize'],
                ]);

            }

        }Вот тут весь код[ссылка](https://searchengines.guru/ru/forum/1047114)